# install build-essentials

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, software-center, update-manager

I have used the command

```
sudo apt-get install build-essentials g++-4.4 gcc-4.4
```

This command gives error

```
E: Unable to locate package build-essentials.
```

how should I install gcc?

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: It's called `build-essential` (without the `s`)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The package I think you want to install is "**build-essential**". If you use the correct name, not "build-essential**s**", you will get better results

Answer (score -1):

run command :

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main"
```

then do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

Comment: AFAIK it's in `main` - there should be no need to add the `universe` repository

Comment: @ steeldriver  thanks !! i have remove that one