# GCC compiler does not recognize in the CodeBlocks IDE (Set variable: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:)

Tags: 20.04, compiling, gcc, c, code-blocks

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and I have been trying to get up and run the C programs in **codeblocks** IDE and it keeps getting me this following error.

```
Checking for existence: /media/darkpheonix/dptech/dptech/Projects/C/techtheory/bin/Debug/techtheory
    Set variable: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:
    Executing: xterm -T techtheory -e /usr/bin/cb_console_runner LD_LIBRARY_PATH=:. /media/darkpheonix/dptech/dptech/Projects/C/techtheory/bin/Debug/techtheory  (in /media/darkpheonix/dptech/dptech/Projects/C/techtheory/.)
    Process terminated with status -1 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

I tried `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`  
Then tried installing the build essential packages from the main server. `sudo apt-get install build-essentials`.  
This keep getting me following error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package build-essential is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'build-essential' has no installation candidate
```

I tried different sources but doesn't seem to solve this issue. Please help

Comment: The media file has been mounted as exact-4 which is the preferred type for Linux.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [install build-essentials](https://askubuntu.com/questions/674449/install-build-essentials)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sudo apt-get install build-essential` This worked. Simply use `essential` not `essentials`

## **Solved it!**

### Step 1

#### *GCC compiler configurations*

You have to run the

> `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/path/to/sdk/lib"`

to export the path to the compilers.  
Default path is in `usr/bin`  
Copy and paste the path into the `your_lib.conf` file in the location `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` then save and exit.

> `sudo ldconfig`

Run this to confirm the changes in the files which added the paths.

### Step 2

#### *`xterm` configuration*

Install `xterm` into the operating system.

> `sudo apt-get install xterm`

Check and make sure that it is in the latest version of the configurations and then test the **CODEBLOCKS** project, build and run them as a console application.

Comment: This answers the `build essential` issue but still has to figure out the `path` error in there. `Set variable: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:` this one

Comment: It worked... I updated the answer